# Confusion with while loop using indexOf

Tags: javascript, algorithm, loops, while-loop, indexof

```
var myString = "Welcome to Example books. The Example website is www.example.com. Visit the Example website today. Thanks for buying Example";
var foundAtPosition = 0;
var exampleCount = 0;
while (foundAtPosition != -1) {
    foundAtPosition = myString.indexOf("Example", foundAtPosition);
    if (foundAtPosition != -1) {
        exampleCount++;
        foundAtPosition++;
    }
}
```

With the above code, I'm little bit confused about how the loop starting point is working. If you take a look, you'll see the `foundAtPosition` used as a starting point of `indexOf()` function. But after the first loop the 
`indexOf()` function will take the `foundAtPosition` value as a starting point and it's `6`, while the `"Example"` word is again found at the index of `0`. So, how is the loop skipping the word from the first result and moving to the next one?

Comment: Why not monitor the variable in the dev console as you step through the code, or else add some `console.log` calls in the loop to output how the value of `foundAtPosition` changes? It is really not that hard to understand...

Comment: you don't need the condition inside the while loop

Comment: @MarouenMhiri yes you do. There are other ways to write it where only one check is needed, but if you unwrap the `if` block in this code, it will not work as intended.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts you're right

Comment: @PatrickRoberts In this case he doesn't need the condition but only expose what  it contains to the while loop. It'a about indexOf !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`myString.indexOf("Example", foundAtPosition);` looks for the first occurance of `"Example"` which is not before `foundAtPosition`.

And this block,

```
if (foundAtPosition != -1) {
    exampleCount++;
    foundAtPosition++;
}
```

increments the foundAtPosition, so the next time the search moves right to the current position.

Answer (score 3):

After the first loop the `indexOf()` function will take 11 not 6.

Here are the loops:

```
foundAtPosition:11 / exampleCount:0
foundAtPosition:27 / exampleCount:1
foundAtPosition:67 / exampleCount:2
foundAtPosition:105 / exampleCount:3
foundAtPosition:-1 / exampleCount:4
```

As you see `indexOf()` function will search for the remaining part of your string, every time after character 11, 27, 67, 105 and it will stop.